# Tick in checkbox in pdf.js

Tags: javascript, css, pdf

I have a data based server side from PHP:

```
$in_array = [];
foreach ($arrayItems as $arrayKey => $arrayItem):
   array_push($in_array, $arrayItem->item_id);
endforeach;

foreach ($dataItems as $datakey => $dataItem):
   if (in_array($dataItem->id, $in_array)) {
     echo '<input type="checkbox" id="ckb" name="ckb[]" value="$dataItem->id" checked="checked" />' . '&nbsp;<label>' . $dataItem->nama_item . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>';
   } else {
     echo '<input type="checkbox" id="ckb" name="ckb[]" value="$dataItem->id" />'. '&nbsp;<label>' . $dataItem->nama_item . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>';
   }
 endforeach;
?>
```

Then I displayed it into pdf using [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/).

I use css :

```
input[type='checkbox'] { 
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: larger;
}
```

Why in tick checkbox pdf.js using X not common tick like this:

[image].

I need just common tick (like the Nike logo).

Answer (score 0):

The appearance of an Adobe Checkbox is left to the options of the "Local" Reader application.

So there is no global answer.

In fact many form elements may not work, nor work the same, in other readers apart from the designer Adobe AcroForm products.

[image]